# Разработка приложения на сокетах в Xamarin Studio

Tags: java, c#, websocket, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Начинаю работать с Xamarin Studio. Хочу написать маленькое приложение для работы с сокетами. Интересует такой вопрос.
В этой же Xamarin приложения пишутся на C#. А у меня стоит сервер Jetty и серверная сторона написана на Java.  И собственно вопрос. Можно ли в таком случае установить двустороннюю связь, т.е. сокет, в данном случае?

Comment: Сокету без разницы на чем написан код, так что установить соединение можно.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо! А что нужно использовать, что бы с этого же веб-сервера посылать запрос к БД и отображать данные клиенту? Точнее, куда копать?

Comment: Перефразирую свой комментарий. Я, как .NET разраб, говорю, что если у вас есть готовый сервер, не важно на чем написан, и этот сервер позволяет подключаться через сокет, то вы можете к нему подключиться, используя .NET технологии. Что касается вашего сервера, то он у вас на Java, и я понятия не имею, что ваш сервер может, и чего не может.